# Subversion: Is there a way to add my .as files but skip my .fla files?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, svn

Is there a way to add .as files to a subversion repository but to get it to skip over my .fla files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have the syntax right, you should be able to do...

```
svn add *.as
svn propset svn:ignore *.fla
svn commit
```

To do it all...

Answer (score 3):

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html

Answer (score 2):

you must edit the Subversion “config” file. You do not mention your platform so I cannot be of more help for it's location.

add:

```
global-ignores = *.fla
```

You can also do it on the command line for a local repo:

```
svn propset svn:ignore *.fla .
```

Comment: I'm using Terminal...does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can ignore the extension fla:

> global-ignores = *.fla